# TFS not finding Office assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, excel, tfs, office-interop

My project references `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and a few other `Office` based assemblies. What is the best way to get `TFS` to find this assemblies?

I would rather avoid having to install the full `Office` on the build server as I am not sure if this will solve the issue, but I cannot find any form of runtime libraries.

I have tried adding the `Office` assemblies to a `Libs` folder in the project and referencing those binaries, but the reference paths are not relative to the project. This is a problem because the directories on the build server and local machine are different.

What do you suggest?

The error I get is:

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to need those assembly purely to be able to build the project on the TFS server. You don't want to run it.

If that is the case, you can install the "Office Primary Interop Assemblies" in the TFS server.